# Robotium get String using ArrayList<TextView>

Tags: android, robotium

Hi i have a listview add random string

now i can using arraylist click item but now need the item string

string is resource not text...

```
ArrayList<TextView> listtest = solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class);
View lt = listtest.get(1);
String text;
text = lt.toString();
solo.clickOnView(lt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear but what i suspect you want is the following:

```
TextView lt = listtest.get(1);
text = lt.getText().toString();
```

Comment: excellent, glad I could help. Just to add extra detail, your toString was calling the tostring on the view itself when the text inside the view is a seperate object.